# How to get back data from php variable to jquery variable using jquery $.POST method

Tags: php, jquery

In the below code the $.POST method passes two variables to the php file empProfile.php which retrieves the employee profile from the database. Know I want to receive ID and Name from the php file to the jquery variables. Can someone help me.

```
data = {
        personnelNo: $('#personnelNo').val(),
        cnic: $('#cnic').val() 
        } //end of data

$.post( 
       "checkEmployee.php",
       data,
       function(data) {
                        var ID =; Name=;


                      } // end of function

      ); // end of post
    //} //end of if statement
}); // end of blur
```

Comment: To answer this, we need to know what your `checkEmployee.php` returns.. Please post that.

Comment: +1 Agree with @techfoobar. We need to know How you return your data from `.php` file?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var ID = '<?php echo $yourId;?>'; 

var Name='<?php echo $yourname;?>';
```

Comment: QA has passed `data` from js to php but now he wants to back assign output from PHP to js from `data` variable which he will receive as a response.

Comment: @NullVoid read the question carefully. he wants to know how to send his php variables with jquery

Comment: @Robin, Question is saying that get `How to get back data from php variable to jquery variable...`. It means he's able to send data from jQuery to PHP but he wants back from PHP to jQuery. And in jQuery response, Will he receive PHP variables?

Comment: `I want to receive ID and Name from the php file to the jQuery variables.` That's the question he is asking. in other words he wants his PHP variables to jQuery

Comment: But it's not possible I think. May be he can send output with some string separator combinationation and then can split it in js and can use it.